# Unexpected behavior of scanf , asks two variable values at the same time

Tags: c

enter image description hereWhen I run the program, first it asks to "write letter A" and then ask to "write letter B and write letter C" at the same time WHY?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char a, b, c;

  printf("write letter A: ");
  scanf("%c",&a);
  printf("write letter B: ");
  scanf("%c",&b);
  printf("write letter C: ");
  scanf("%c",&c);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you enter the first character, you actually enter _two_ characters. The second one is `'\n'`.

Comment: still didn't worked

Comment: Sir  please write the Right code and send to me

Comment: @Mr.SagheerHussainZardari check my answer it might help you